# Regex - find if beginning of line contains a string. If so replace with backspace

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write a regular expression to help locate some carriage return issues. I generated a string at the beginning of each line that I know should start that line. So I can assume that if the line does not contain that string there was a carriage return.

I was able to do it like so:

`\n[^SOMEWORD]`

the `\n` also gets the previous lines space so in the Replace With section I would like to replace that with a backspace so that line will be moved back up but retain that data.

```
SOMEWORD,111111,22222222,null,null,"1333333
4444",55555,66,null,7777777,8888 99999,null,null,null,0,null,false,false,1212121,null,null,null,false,null,null,333333,null

SOMEWORD,111111,22222222,null,null,"1333333
4444",55555,66,null,7777777,8888 99999,null,null,null,0,null,false,false,1212121,null,null,null,false,null,null,333333,null
```

would look like:

```
SOMEWORD,111111,22222222,null,null,"1333333, 4444",55555,66,null,7777777,8888 99999,null,null,null,0,null,false,false,1212121,null,null,null,false,null,null,333333,null
SOMEWORD,111111,22222222,null,null,"1333333, 4444",55555,66,null,7777777,8888 99999,null,null,null,0,null,false,false,1212121,null,null,null,false,null,null,333333,null
```

Comment: Could you please mention the language in which you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this is just in vs code with a csv file. Using regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
(?m)\n(?!SOMEWORD,|$)
```

And replace with `", "` string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JdYPad/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable multiline mode
- `\n`: Match a line break
- `(?!SOMEWORD,|$)`: Assert that there is no `SOMEWORD,` or an empty line ahead

Comment: Seems he actually wants to replace with comma, but that is of course also possible.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak, answer has been updated